# How to route all snmp request to remote deivces from a local machine through a proxy server

Tags: linux, networking, udp, snmp

I have to forward all snmp request to remote deivces from a local machine to proxy server. Is it possible ?

The actual requirement is like i have set of network devices that are only accessible through machine A. Machine A and network devices are in same network. Now i have to send snmp request to devices from a machine B that is outside the network and it has not access to newtwork devices.Network devices can be only accessed through machine A.
So i am looking a solution by which i can forward all snmp request on machine B for network devices to machine A over ssh , is it possible ? if yes then any solution will be much appreciated.

I am looking solution similer to http://www.morch.com/2011/07/05/forwarding-snmp-ports-over-ssh-using-socat/ but in this solution snmp agent is server as remote server (running snmp agent code on machine A) but in my case remote server A and snmp agent (devices ) are different.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution might be installing net-snmp on Host A and configure it as a snmp proxy like that:

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Snmpd_proxy

Comment: To use net-snmp's snmpd as a pure proxy you need to build it yourself from source without any built-in MIB modules. If you don't build it without MIB modules, the proxying behavior will not be what you expect from a pure proxying agent.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. That is something I wasn't aware of. Would you recommend deleting the answer, or should I leave it for clarification?

Comment: I would recommend *improving* the answer. Building open source SNMP proxies is not simple. Part of the problem is that the net-snmp implementations of getnext and getbulk do not necessarily give you the results that you want or expect when different parts of a MIB are proxied from different agents. The main problem that I have with your answer is that it appears to be a suggestion that does not have actual personal experience to back it up. All the best.

Comment: Yes, Jonathan. You are right. I lack this personal experience. Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce this any more.